# Why email is not sent when running with Jenkin? It works fine in local

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Function to send emailable-report.html via email is not working when run from Jenkins but it works fine in local.

I have a function just to send email with emailable-report.html after test case execution. It is works fine in my local machine. However when run from Jenkins, build success but no email is sent. I already set hostname and smtp port is matched with Jenkins server.

```
String reportLocation ="..\\target\\surefire-reports\\emailable-report.html";  
        EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();

        attachment.setPath(reportLocation);
        attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
        attachment.setDescription("Test Report " + timeStamp + ".html");


        // Create the email message
        MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
        email.setHostName("x.x.x.x"); //SERVER .
        email.setSmtpPort(25);
        email.addTo("user@gmail.com");
        email.setFrom("//another email address", "Me");
        email.setSubject("Selenium WebDriver Test Report, run from Jenkin (SERVER) " + dateTest); 
        email.setMsg("-- This is a Test Report email. Please refer to the attachment for more details!");

        email.attach(attachment);

        // send the email
        email.send();
        System.out.println("Test Report Mail  Sent Successfully");
```

Comment: any error on jenkins console??

Comment: Thanks Jain. No, it’s buil successfully. No any error

Answer (score 0):

Try "Extended E-mail Notification" in jenkins instead of custom functions.

Comment: Thanks Nanda!
 I did try Extend email Notifications on Jenkins however it sent the report as text format in email body instead of html (as on opens on browser). Also It did not send the attachment (emailable-report.html) as expected. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: Attachment from jenkins will move to spam folder by default so please check your  email spam folder .

Comment: For body type you can select the type as either html or text in email configuration itslef

Comment: Hi Nandal,
The attachment is not in spam folder either inbox. I set the body is html but still not working.
I can't attach the screenshot here for more details. Might be it easier if you can see anything not right

Comment: Check whether you have mentioned the proper path in attachment section under "Editable Email Notifiaction".For example if your report is under folder "TestReport"(Project/TestReport/report.html) then mention the path as "**/TestReport/Report.html" .                                                                                   
    One more suggestion is If you have an account in amazon s3 bucket you can upload your report to s3 and share the link in e-mail .For this approach you have to use "Amazon S3 profiles"  plugin in jenkins.

Comment: I set the path is ${FILE, path=”**/target/surefire-reports/custom-report.html”} but this showing this as a text in the email. And no attachment were included with the email. Attachment also set with the same path as above.
The Default Content and Attachment has the same ${FILE, path=”**/target/surefire-reports/custom-report.html”}

Comment: As i am unable to attach the image here i have posted the separate comment..pls refer

Answer (score 0):

Hi@Chau looks like you are passing the path in email body.Instead refer my screenshot where i have mentioned the path separately under Attahments in "Editable Email Notification"[image]

Comment: Thank you Sadha. The Report now is sent with attachment. I'll try to upload report on Amazon S3 as your suggestion.